# How to prevent resizing of div cover image during draggabilly.js drag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building an image gallery. Users can drag-drop their photos to add them to albums. I'm using draggabilly.js, and my draggable thumbnails are divers with a `background-image:url` and `background-size: cover`.

I've run into a strange issue where, whenever a thumbnail is selected, the background image size reverts to its original size until the selection is released.

This codepen will explain much better, just drag one of the images at the top.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpvVVz

Is there a way to prevent the image size reverting while being dragged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you overwrite background-size with:

```
.is-dragging {
  background: #4D90FE;
}
```

Use

```
.is-dragging {
  background-color: #4D90FE;
}
```

instead

http://codepen.io/zba/pen/eNMOpp